# How do I add a curve to a vertex to bend an edge / face

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices

*Context: I'm extremely new to Blender (using Mac) and 3D modelling in general and I'm trying to add the final touches on my first model.*

For my model, I am aiming to construct a 3D model of a box packaging for a product using the die cut I have received from the manufacturer. I intend to import my final model into Adobe Dimension so I can texturise it and add my mockup label.

I have managed to create my box ~90% with as accurate dimensions as I can. I have achieved this by starting out with a cube and extruded faces and adding edges. My issue lies in the remaining 10% whereby I need to add some curves to my model.

**This is my model so far ~90%**

[image: My current model]

**What I need to adjust are the curves on the side and back to be similar to the die cut as illustrated below**
[image: Side Curve]
[image: Back Curve]

**Essentially, I need to adjust my faces/edges of my model to look something like this:**
[image: Target Curve 1]
[image: Target Curve 2]

I come from a graphic design background and so am used to drawing objects and shapes using Pen tools and adding curves via handles. As such, I would greatly appreciate the a full walkthrough to the solution as if you were to explain it to a 5 year old :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) on the edges you want to curve. Once you have beveled, select "Custom Profile" from the operator panel that appears, and you can define all aspects of the bevel, including custom curvature. In the example below, I deformed it heavily on purpose just to demonstrate. If you line up your object in front of a reference image, you can replicate the curve precisely.

[image: Bevel]

Comment: @Awesome! That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for :) I'm having a little trouble with the bevel curves unfortunately,

Comment: Remember to adjust the size of the bevel beforehand by moving the mouse when you bevel (to approximate the size of the "curve" you want to make) - you can also adjust the number of segments by scrolling the mouse wheel. Also remember that you can add as many points as you want to  the curve profile - just click on the line.

Comment: sorry for the previous comment -> I didn't finish it due to a trigger happy pinky finger :')

Do I select both edges when pressing CMD+B? My segments, don't seem to be horizontally across the face as yours are. Instead, Mine are vertically down the side face :( [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qNG3VOy1KKOGMuxon3jZSYveCJ5ezWIH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can do as many edges as you want, but I recommend only selecting ones that you want to be the "same". If they're going sideways, you're probably beveling the wrong edge (I used the little one at the top). As a last important point, remember to make sure scale is applied in object mode before you do this. A non-uniform scale will cause wonky results (as it will with many things).

Comment: ahh you sir, are a saviour! I've been struggling over this for days :'( I should have turned to this forum sooner haha! Another quick question if you wouldn't mind? I've selected the edge at the top on both sides and then pressed CMD+B but only the right side seems to be bevelling. Even when I try the left side's edge on its own, it doesn't seem to segment. Do you have any idea why this may be happening? [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tQZQ0dl84ZJdPWuxi9bfyGn5wCHObdqW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Not sure. Maybe the edges aren't connected properly? Try selecting all and then press M (merge) and select "by distance" to make sure you're gotten rid of any dupes, and maybe try recalculating the normals outside? I'm just guessing here - it's hard to tell without seeing the actual model.

Comment: Thank you so much Christopher! I've now been able to complete my model, exactly how I wanted - honestly couldn't achieve it without your help. I've spent days Googling all sorts phrases and have tried countless solutions from adding empty objects and modifiers to using bezier curves. If only from the beginning I knew how simple it was! Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey, glad it works. Yeah, that's one of my favorite things about blender - for many seemingly complicated problems, chances are a few people have come across it before and a simple solution has since been built into the engine. It's only a matter of finding the right search term....